# Special nginx hotlink protection conversion from Apache .htaccess rule

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, apache-2.4

I have the following anti-leeching rewrite rule in Apache, which i'd like to have in nginx. I see cookie or referrer rule examples. But none combining both, so I am not sure how to go about this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www.)?domain\.com.*$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*_.*$
    RewriteRule \.(flv|jpg|jpeg|mp3|mpg|mp4|mov|wav|wmv|png|gif|swf|css|js|htc|woff|otf|eot|ttf)$ - [F,NS,L]
</IfModule>
```

It's a slightly relaxed rule which allows empty referrers if sent with a known cookie (`_` for the example). But it will deny access without that cookie set when using invalid domain referrers.